# SOQL 101 error too many quries - No query inside inside of any loops

Tags: apex, soql

I created a function to move leads from someone who is on vacation however when A user has over 100 leads this error gets thrown even though I dont call soql queries inside of the for loops. Perhaps I am missing something here and I would greatly appreciate any kind of help on this.

```
trigger Moveleads on User (after update) {
for(User user: System.Trigger.New)  
{ 
    if(user.On_Vacation__c == true ){
        if(user.User_to_send_leads_to__c == null){
            user.addError('Must specify someone to take their leads');
            user.On_Vacation__c = false;
        }else{
            Lead[] leadsToMove = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, From_someone_on_Vaction__c, Status FROM lead 
                                                                  WHERE OwnerId = :user.Id];
            string userToTakeLeads = user.User_to_send_leads_to__c;
            for(lead x : leadsToMove){
                if(x.From_someone_on_Vaction__c == false && x.Status == 'Not Attempted'){
                    x.OwnerId = userToTakeLeads;
                    x.From_someone_on_Vaction__c = true;
                    x.User_leads_are_from__c = user.id;
                }
            }
            Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
            dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
            dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
            dlo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;
            dlo.OptAllOrNone = false;
            database.update(leadsToMove,dlo);
        }
    }else{
        Lead[] leadsToMove = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, From_someone_on_Vaction__c, Status FROM lead WHERE 
                                                              User_leads_are_from__c = :user.Id];
        for(lead x : leadsToMove){
            if(x.From_someone_on_Vaction__c == true){
                x.OwnerId = user.Id;
                x.From_someone_on_Vaction__c = false;
                x.User_leads_are_from__c = '';
            }
        }
        Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
        dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
        dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
        dlo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;
        dlo.OptAllOrNone = false;
        database.update(leadsToMove,dlo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see your SOQL is inside the `for(User user: System.Trigger.New)` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire logic to your code is inside the following loop:

`for(User user: System.Trigger.New)`

You are also doing the DML (`database.update(leadsToMove,dlo);`) inside the same loop

Since Salesforce processes triggers in batches of up to 200 records, you will hit Governor Limits every time you update more than 100 users at a time.

You have two queries that can be moved outside of that loop. I will illustrate a potential fix with one of them:

```
Map<Id, List<Lead>> leadsPerUser = new Map<Id, List<Lead>>();
for (Lead l : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, From_someone_on_Vaction__c, Status FROM lead WHERE OwnerId in :Trigger.newMap().keySet()]) {
    if (! leadsPerUser.containsKey(l.OwnerId) {
      leadsPerUser.put(l.OwnerId, new List<Lead>());
    }

    List<Lead> leads = leadsPerUser.get(l.OwnerId);
    leads.add(l);
    leadsPerUser.put(l.OwnerId, leads);
}
```

Then, below, simply get the list based on the owner you're iterating by and process as you're currently doing.

```
 List<Lead> leadsToMove = leadsPerUser.get(user.Id);
//Note, Don't forget to check for existence, a user may not have leads)
```

I would also do the following changes:

1. remove all the dml parts from inside the loop
2. when a lead must be changed, add it to a new list
3. do DML on that list after the for loop.

Quick example

```
//Avoid updating the same lead twice
Map<Id, Lead> leadsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Lead>();
for (User u .... ) {
<for loop logic>
    for(lead x : leadsToMove){
       <logic of if statement>
       leadsToUpdate.put(x.id, x);
    }
<rest of for loop logic>
update leadsToUpdate;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

You do have a query in a loop, it's the else statement:

```
for(User user: System.Trigger.New)  
{ 
  if(user.On_Vacation__c == true ){
    ...
  }else{
    Lead[] leadsToMove = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, From_someone_on_Vaction__c, Status FROM lead WHERE ...
```

You will need to optimize this part of the logic so that this query is only performed once.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out